Is Samadhi experienced through the Crown Chakra only?
Generally, the Crown Chakra appears to be associated with the attainment of Samadhi.
Is this final state of Yoga also experienced through the Anahata (heart) Chakra?
If so, is there a difference in the Samadhis experienced through the two Chakras?
धन्यवादः

According to Ramakrishna and his disciples, Savikalpa samadhi occurs when the kundalini reaches the ajna chakra. Nirviklpa samadhi occurs when it reaches the sahasrara chakra:

To explain fully: there is the spinal column, where all the centers
are located. In the spinal column is a central canal and there are
channels on either side, the left called ida, the right called
pingala. The center is called sushumna. There is no function in the
central channel of the spine; our life energy ordinarily flows through
the channels on the right and left. Now, the life energy has to be
made to flow through the central channel, through the sushumna. It is
technically known as the doorway to Brahman. The moment any spiritual
energy flows through that central channel, a new consciousness
evolves, just as one who is blind might get physical sight and so
begin to experience the world in a new way.
At the base of the spine
is a triple knot of spiritual nerves forming a triangle, and within
that triangle is the kundalini, the coiled-up energy. It looks like a
serpent, as thin as the thread of a lotus stalk. This center at the
base of the spine, the muladhara, is the seat of the subconscious
mind.
The next center is technically called svadhisthana. It is
situated at the root of the genitals and is said to be the seat of
lust and greed. The lotus bud there has six petals. If the energy
rises to this center, there comes, to a degree, the conquest of lust
and greed.
The next center, the manipura, is situated at the root of
the navel and has ten petals. It is the seat of psychic power. As the
energy rises to that center through the sushumna, psychic visions and
experiences and occult powers manifest.
The next center is the center
of the heart, which is technically called anahata. But before I come
to that, let me point out how most people’s minds are within these
three lower centers: worldliness, lust, physical enjoyment, and
experience. Their minds are downward, and until there is an attempt to
make the mind move upward, there can be no spiritual growth. You may
go to church, you may read, you may do good work; they may help you,
but until there is an awakening of the higher centers, there can be no
spiritual growth.
All kinds of impulses are in us. If we say we have
to satisfy these impulses because they are there, we remain in the
animal, beastly, plane. It is only by overcoming these impulses that
there is any possibility of spiritual growth. We cannot even think of
God as long as the mind remains within the lower centers of
consciousness. If we think of God at all, God is accepted as a means
to realize our selfish and personal ends and to attain our personal
satisfaction in the physical plane.
So the anahata is located in the
heart. When the kundalini rises to this spiritual center – this is
really the first spiritual center – one has the vision of spiritual
life. There comes an illumination. Anahata literally means “unstruck
sound.” Sound is produced by striking two objects, but as the mind is
lifted up to this spiritual center, one can hear the spiritual sound,
which is produced without striking two bodies. While one is in that
spiritual center, there is the experience of a spiritual life, and one
hears the Cosmic Word, the Cosmic Sound, OM.
Here again, let me
explain that this whole creation comes out of the thought of God.
Thought and word are identical. If you study any philosophy, you will
find this truth brought out – that the whole universe came out of the
thought of God and that thought and word are identical. Hindus claim
that this word OM is the first word that arose after creation, that
the whole creation proceeds from the word. Creation, then, is a kind
of degeneration, and to rise above creation is to become regenerated.
The creation is outgoing, it is degeneration; and regeneration is to
go back to God. Now in the process of going back to God we retrace, as
it were, the same process by which there is creation. Creation
proceeded from the sound OM, and regeneration begins with the sound
OM.
The next higher center, at the throat, is called the vishuddha,
which literally means purity. When the mind with the kundalini comes
to this center of spiritual consciousness, there is a complete
regeneration, complete transformation. It is said that one, through
spiritual struggles, may rise to the center in the heart, but there is
always the possibility of being dragged down to the lower centers. But
if the mind rises to this center called the vishuddha, one becomes
established in purity: nothing, no worldliness, can drag the aspirant
down again. The outward sign is that the individual cannot think of
anything but God, cannot speak of anything but God, cannot hear of
anything but God. If somebody talks about worldly things, there comes
a real, physical pain.
The next higher center, called ajna, is between
the eyebrows. Ajna literally means command. Here one attains what we
technically call savikalpa samadhi. Through absorption there comes the
direct experience of God in his personal aspect, but there still
remains a separation from God. Here one hears the voice of God with
the command to give blessings to others. In other words, one really
becomes a spiritual teacher. In the life of Sri Ramakrishna we read
how he would approach spiritual teachers and ask, “Have you yet the
command of God?” They didn’t even understand what he meant. Some would
say they have heard the voice of God asking them to go and teach, but
whether it was the voice of God or ego, they did not know. But this is
a direct command, a direct vision and communion.
At one time my master
said he did not do anything without the will of God. I asked him,
“What do you mean by the will of God? The same way I or anybody can
think and do something and then impute that to the will of God?” One
can very sincerely feel that he is doing something by the will of God.
Most spiritual souls try to do that and try to wipe out their ego. But
when I asked my master if that is what he meant, he said, “No.” I
said, “Do you mean to say that you see him and he talks to you?” He
said, “Yes.” A direct communion – to see God, to talk to God – is
possible. When the mind comes to that spiritual center within the
eyebrows, you have a direct communion with God.
Sri Ramakrishna used
to say that when the mind comes there, there is still the separation,
still the ego left: I hear the will of God, I see him. But one feels
like a moth before a fire. The fire is protected by a glass, and the
moth beats and beats against that glass to jump into the fire. The
same desire arises to beat against that separation and to attain to
the highest center, called “the thousand-petalled,” the sahasrara, in
the brain.
There the kundalini becomes united with Shiva, with
Paramatman, the higher Universal Self. And there is complete union.
That is nirvikalpa samadhi, the Absolute. When the mind rises to that
highest center in the brain, there is no longer any vision or
experience: There is the knowledge of union.

Source: "Realizing God: Lectures on Vedanta" by Swami Prabhavananda
In other words, there are various degrees of awakening that are related to the chakras through which the kundalini rises. Other traditions will have slightly different definitions of samadhi, but in general I resonate more with Ramakrishna's explanations. Regarding the heart chakra, it's a step in the spine that will take the meditator to samadhi.

great answer..corroborating quote: "Sushumna nerve which goes upward from the heart to the centre of the skull is considered the doorway to realization."

As per Sri M (Nath Yogi), if the Manipura is fully balanced and the Yogi has moved upwards, then also there's no returning back to material life. Thanks for the answer.
